# Deduplication on Amazon Athena

Tags: hive, amazon-athena, presto

We have streaming applications storing data on S3. The S3 partitions might have duplicated records. We query the data in S3 through Athena.

Is there a way to remove duplicates from S3 files so that we don't get them while querying from Athena?

Answer (score 3):

Please use CTAS:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
WITH (
      format = 'Parquet',
      parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY')
AS SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM old_table;
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small bash script that executes a hive/spark/presto query for reading the dat, removing the duplicates and then writing it back to S3.

I don't use Athena but since it is just presto then I will assume you can do whatever can be done in Presto.

The bash script does the following :

- Read the data and apply a distinct filter (or whatever logic you want to apply) and then insert it to another location.

For Example :

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.newTable AS
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM hive.schema.myTable
```

- If it is a recurring task, then INSER OVERWRITE would be better.
- Don't forget to set the location of the hive db to easily identify the data destination.

Syntax Reference : https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table.html

- Remove the old data directory using [aws s3 CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html).
- Move the new data to the old directory

Now you can safely read the same table but the records would be distinct.

Comment: Though your suggestions are correct, Athena doesn't provide anyway of inserting or updating the data. So INSERT OVERWRITE won't work. I guess will have to write EMR jobs to achieve the same

Comment: You don't really need to use Athena in this. You can use any of the other suggested engines.

Comment: Since you are using AWS then you can use data piplines to run this job everyday via Spark for example in case you don't have a Hadoop setup.

Comment: Can't ditch athena, a client requirement. :| But, I get what you are saying. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Athena can make **EXTERNAL TABLE** on data stored in S3. If you want to modify existing data then use HIVE.

- Create a table in hive.
- `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE new_table_name  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table;`

Answer (score -1):

We can not remove duplicate in Athena as it works on file it have work arrounds.

So some how duplicate record should be deleted from files in s3, most easy way would be shellscript.

Or

Write select query with distinct option.

Note: Both are costly operations.